# How to edit code with error that immediately closes the workbook after it is opened? Runtime error 49 Bad DLL Calling Convention

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro-enabled Excel project in which I have caused

> error 49 Bad DLL calling convention.

I made an edit (which compiled but didn't run). Now when I open the workbook it produces the error then closes so I can't open the VBA code editor to fix the problem.

I tried opening in protected mode and read-only mode - same problem.

I tried repair mode as well - same behavior.

Any way to get past the error and into the VBA editor?

Comment: Do you have a workbook_open event that triggers the code? In that case you might try to open a blank Workbook, go to VBA and use the "immediate" Window to fill in "Application.enableevents = false" and afterwards open your Excel workbook.

Comment: Thanks Alex de Jong - disabling Application events did the trick!